# Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in

Tags: php, javascript, html, zend-framework, magento

I would like to ask for some help with this error I am getting in Magento

Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 163

I have created a CMS page and added a template.phtml file using this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" product_id="177" template="page/thumbnails.phtml"}}
```

The template file shows a product image and thumbnails using the product id. The code works when I place it in view.phtml but when I add it to the CMS page I get the error and I just don't know why?

Id really appreciate some help plese...

Code for thumbnails.phtml:

```
                        <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_gallery = $this->getGalleryImages();
    $_resize = 265;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .product-img-box .more-views li.slide-current a{ border:2px solid #aaa; }
    .product-img-box .product-image-zoom img { cursor: pointer; }
    #slide-loader{ visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top:auto; left:auto; right:2px;      bottom:2px; width: 25px; height: 25px; }
</style>
<p class="product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize($_resize).'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" onclick="popWin(\''.$this->getGalleryUrl().'.\', \'gallery\', \'width=300,height=300,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes\'); return false;" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image')
    ?>
    <img id="slide-loader" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" />
</p>
<p class="a-center" id="track_hint"><?php echo $this->__('Click on above image to view full picture') ?></p>

<?php if (count($_gallery) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h4><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h4>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($_gallery as $_image): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" onclick="slide('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize($_resize) ?>',<?php echo ($s = isset($s) ? ++$s : 0) ?>,'<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>'); return false;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function slide(url,num,gallery){
    if (typeof slide.loading == 'undefined') slide.loading = false;
    if(slide.loading) return false;

    var loader = new Image();
    $(loader).observe('load', function(){

        $('slide-loader').setStyle({'visibility':'hidden'});

        $$('div.more-views li').each(function(el,i){
            (i==num) ? el.addClassName('slide-current') : el.removeClassName('slide-current');
        });

        var dummy = new Element('img', { src: url }).setOpacity(0);
        new Insertion.After('image', dummy);
        new Effect.Opacity(dummy, { duration:.5, from:0, to:1.0 });
        new Effect.Opacity($('image'), { duration:.5, from:1.0, to:0, 
             afterFinish: function(){
                 $('image').writeAttribute('src',url).setOpacity(1).observe('click',function(e){
                     Event.stop(e);
                     popWin(gallery, 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=50,top=50,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); 
                     return false;
                 })
                 dummy.remove();
                 slide.loading = false;
             }
        });
    });

    $('slide-loader').setStyle({'visibility':'visible'});
    loader.src=url;
    slide.loading = true;
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: where are you calling `getdata()`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm basically trying to add media.phtml file to a static block the above code is slightly different in terms of styling but works when I place in the media.phtml file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this code is used in view.phtml your block class is not going to be core/template therefore references such as "$this->getImageLabel()" will cause you the errors you describe.

To see this problem for yourself add this to the top of both view.phtml and thumbnails.phtml

```
echo get_class($this);
```

You could then update your inline static block type. From memory it could be catalog/product but you can easily figure this out once you've done the suggestion above.

```
{{block type="catalog/product" product_id="177" template="page/thumbnails.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your responses. Really helpful. I must point out that I made a mistake with the file names. Instead of view.phtml the above code^ works in media.phtml as both are essentially carrying out the same function of calling images and displaying them for the particular product.

Comment: I've also changed the block code to the above^                                                                                       which throws the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php on line 35

Comment: Okay, not sure where to go now `<?php echo get_class($this); ?>` tells me `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media` but nothing for thumbnails.phtml. I've also changed the block code to `{{block type="catalog/product" product_id="177" template="page/thumbnails.phtml"}}` which gives me an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php on line 35`

Comment: if the class is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media then you should change your block type from "catalog/product" to something like "catalog/product_view_media".

Comment: I've tried adding other .phtml files to the CMS page which also cause me errors but work in the normal site. I think for some reason adding .phtml files that contain php code to CMS pages causes an issue... I've been searching around the web allday and cannot find a solution for this either!

Comment: Changed the block type to catalog/product_view_media I get an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getTypeInstance() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Abstract.php on line 44`

Comment: changed the class to cayalog/product_vew and the error is gone and have an image showing but not thumbnails and when image is clicked it takes me to the homepage. Nevertheless  it got rid of the error which is what I asked you to help me to do - Thankyou!